# How to keep state at the and of an :enter animation

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have a very basic animation in angular

```
transition(':enter', [
  query('.form', [
    style({ opacity: 0, top: 0 }),
    animate('1000ms ease-in', style({ opacity: 1, top: 100 }))
 ]),
]),
```

And the HTML

```
<div @myAnimation *ngIf="showForm">
    <div class="form">....</form>
</div>
```

It seems that state can be kept using `state`, so I tried adding

```
 state('*', style({ opacity: 1, top: 100 }))
```

or

```
state('true', style({ opacity: 1, top: 100 }))
```

In which I changed the HTML: `[@myAnimation]="showForm"`

and the animation

```
transition(':enter', [
  state('*', style({ opacity: 1, top: 100 }))
  query('.form', [
    style({ opacity: 0, top: 0 }),
    animate('1000ms ease-in', style({ opacity: 1, top: 100 }))
  ]),
]),
```

Any suggestions why the state is still not persisted at the end?

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve that using animation fill mode [`forwards`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode#syntax). The following code should work properly:

```
transition(':enter', [
  state('*', style({ opacity: 1, top: 100 }))
  query('.form', [
    style({ opacity: 0, top: 0 }),
    animate('1000ms ease-in forwards', style({ opacity: 1, top: 100 }))
  ]),
]),
```

Comment: It seems that this is not allowed in angular, it gives errors:  `The animation trigger "barfoo" has failed to build due to the following errors: The provided timing value "500ms ease-in forwards" is invalid.`